# Install haguichi on raspberry pi

Tags: vpn

I already have hamachi installed and its connected to my vpn on my other windows pc.
I would like to also install the GUI part of hamachi?

I'm trying to install haguichi using this line of code here:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/haguichi 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install haguichi
```

but when on the first line i get the error

```
 sudo add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not install PPA's onto your Raspberry distribution because of those for prepared for Ubuntu. If you are sure those PPA's for your distribution, you have install some packages to avoid these errors.

First of all; find the deb package which contains program/application/script that you cannot run. Then install the package.

```
$ apt-file search add-apt-repository  
python-software-properties: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository

$ apt-get install python-software-properties
```