# Configuring Hamachi on Haguichi Raspberry

Tags: vpn

I just installed hamachi and haguichi. I thought my hamachi is already setup cause when I try to enter `sudo hamachi` i see the version number, pid, status (logged in), client id, address, nickname and lmi account.

But when I opened Haguichi, it says

```
Hamachi is not configured. You need to configure Hamachi before you can connect
```

Then I try to click the Configure button but nothing happens.

But I already have hamachi installed and configured already.

I found this on the Haguichi site:

```
By default Hamachi can only be controlled by the root user on your system. 
To allow other users (such as yourself) to control Hamachi you need to add the line 
Ipc.User username to the file /var/lib/logmein-hamachi/h2-engine-override.cfg where 
username is your actual username. If you click the "Configure" button then will add     
this line for you. However you do need to have (root or super user) privileges to be     
able to do so.
```

I looked for the file `h2-engine-override.cfg` under that directory but its not there.

And I checked if my user have root priviledges, and it has.

I'm going nuts with this Haguichi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install haguichi on raspberry pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15437/install-haguichi-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: how is this a duplicate? On my previous post I was told to start a new question if there is something specific that I want to know or need help with.

Comment: Did you try to create the `h2-engine-override.cfg`-file? Can you find a `h2-engine.cfg` file somewhere? (Try `sudo find / -name h2-engine.cfg`.) Why do you think your user has `root`privileges?

Comment: @Bex i did sudo find h2-engine.cfg and the output was just h2-engine.cfg, and yes i found the file also

Comment: @lenik The OP *is* correct. He *was* told to create a new question if he needed help with configuring Haguichi, as that *is not* the same as installing. I don't agree with that duplicate vote.

Comment: @CCK Ok, good. So, edit that file and have a look at its content. You can probably make you addition into that file, but better would probably be to follow have  look at the formatting in that file and create an override file as per the instructions you have.